# unzip and maintain directory structure of archives

Tags: zip, fedora-13

On fedora-13, I tried using:

```
unzip -j [nameof.zip]
```

but this doesn't seem to maintain the folder structure of the original archive. I REALLY need to maintain this structure because the archive is a backup of all my m4a's which are being converted to mp3. If I just convert it as is, then i'll just have a single massive directory full of mp3's, but they won't be in their respective "artist" folder.

Comment: I don't want to be downvoted for this, because the solution sounds trolly, what you need to do is: man unzip
it will show you the flag you need, good luck.

Comment: @Guillermo that is not a 'solution', that's a pointer in the direction of getting a solution, and rightly a comment rather than an answer. The answers point out exactly what the OP needs to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's much better now, Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to invoke unzip without the -j.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the directory structure then you **really** need to drop the flag that tells `unzip` to junk the paths.